# Any ways to resuming download on HG or GIT changsets pulling?

Tags: python, git, mercurial

I try to find way for update speсial software (Python application) on client.
Client already have HG or GIT, and I can dictate any requirements for client environment.

But client have slowly and breaking out internet connection.

HG, GIT and others tools ideal for update procedure by changesets with minimal traffic bandwidth.

But if changesets became big (jump from small revision number to HEAD) downloading them may
be cancled by connection lost.

Can HG, GIT or others resuming download by pull commands?

---

One way to use bundle of changesets, download them with wget/curl and others with resuming download option. Then apply bundle.

In this solution server must provide bundles for every revision jumps combination  FROM to TO (1-2, 1-15, 2-15). Ideally server must have "Lazzy bundle creation" by client request.

```
wget -c https://repo.myserver.com/bundle?from=rev1&to=rev2
```

---

Has any others ways for client software update from source code repository?

Sorry for my poor English :(

Thanks

Comment: I can't comment on the broken connection issue, but regarding downloading a bundle - you would not need a bundle for each FROM to TO combination. You could provide a bundle with the entire repository, and perhaps a bundle with 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 of the repository (just the later changesets in each bundle). Then just pick the one that's needed (the smallest bundle that contains the required changeset). The client can get a bundle with more changesets than needed, and just `pull` from that as if it were a repo. If your repo is small, just provide the full repo as a bundle.

Comment: Have you considered using rsync?

Comment: I am not considered using rsync, because source code must update direct from central repository and applied in "transaction" (all parts in one operation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is particularly efficient and resilient for such network breakdown effects.

Efficient because, it only pulls the objects in the tree that are changed or newly added and even transmits the compressed objects.

Resilient because, unless all the necessary objects are present, the branch is not furthered. That is a merge happens only after the fetch is complete.

If ever the fetch were to be interpreted, the next time the fetch is executed, only the new objects that were not earlier received will be received, this time.

Bundling--transferring-through-wget--applying-bundle is obviously fail proof, but I am not so sure, if that is really necessary.